# Clone server to docker image

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile

I have Centos server and there is a lot of configuration that there is no documentation of it.

I need to make a clone of that server in docker image so i can use it for different code.

Is there a script,software or service can do that for me ?

Comment: Just use the image that you pulled and make changes. As long as you dont push it back, that changes are just with you. What is concerning to you?

Comment: @Rao  the Centos is not docker image its regular server

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but i Wagely understand that you are trying to upload a customised image so that you can take the same image again for repeated usage. If my understanding is right here is the solution for you have a look at this : https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerimages/

Comment: thanks but the Centos is not docker image its regular server i need a way to clone it as docker image